# Is the phrase 'the delusive nature of' related to next phrases?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, modifiers

In this following context, is the phrase 'the delusive nature of' related to the next bold and italic phrases as:

'the delusive nature of ego-entity,

the delusive nature of the mere relative value of the ego-feeling,

the delusive nature of the great
dependency of this tiny man..'?

Or does the underlined phrases modify the phrase 'the delusive nature of ego-entity'?

How should I know this sentence?

Context:

> About the this unreality of the ego, the Hungarian psychologist Volgyesi […] says:
>
> Under the influence of the newest knowledge the psychologists already begin to realize the truth about the delusive nature of the
> ego-entity, ***the mere relative value of the ego-feeling, the great dependency of this tiny man on the inexhaustible and complex working factors of the whole world***…

Source: [*Collected Wheel Publications* Vol.XXVI](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Collected_Wheel_Publications_Volume_XXVI/Dgc4BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E2%80%9Cthe%20mere%20relative%20value%20of%20the%20ego-feeling,%20the%20great%20dependency%20of%20this%20tiny%20man%20on%20the%20inexhaustible%E2%80%9D&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

That's a complex sentence! No wonder you are unsure.

I would read it as a list separated by commas. In the sentence "I went shopping for apples, oranges, strawberries," the list items are not connected grammatically. The only connection is that they are all items to be purchased by the shopper.

So here, read it as a list of truths that are being realised. It becomes clearer if we reword it slightly like this.

> Under the influence of the newest knowledge the psychologists already
> begin to realize the truth about the following subjects:
>
> - the delusive nature of the ego-entity;
> - the mere relative value of the ego-feeling;
> - (and) the great dependency of this tiny man on the inexhaustible and    complex working factors of the whole world.

Note that I've added **and** to this rewording, which is what you would usually expect in a list. It's possible that we can read the sentence another way, as three phrases which mean the same thing. In that case it would be saying:

> Under the influence of the newest knowledge the psychologists already
> begin to realize the truth about the delusive nature of the
> ego-entity (in other words the mere relative value of the ego-feeling, the great
> dependency of this tiny man on the inexhaustible and complex working
> factors of the whole world.)

I think this is less likely, but I don't know enough about the subject to be sure. If that is the intended meaning, then it's clumsily written.

Either way, we can be sure that your suggestion in the original post is not correct. "Delusive" is not intended to apply to all three phrases. For example, "delusive nature" applies to the ego-entity, and "the mere relative value" applies separately to the ego-feeling, and "great dependency" applies (again separately) to the rest of the sentence. We are saying the same thing if we create three separate sentences like this:

- The psychologists already begin to realize the truth about the
  delusive nature of the ego-entity...
- The psychologists already begin to realize the truth about the mere
  relative value of the ego-feeling...
- The psychologists already begin to realize the truth about the great
  dependency of this tiny man on the inexhaustible and complex working
  factors of the whole world.

Answer (score 0):

"the delusive nature" applies syntactically to the "ego-entity", not to the subsequent phrases.

> Under the influence of the newest knowledge the psychologists already begin to realize the truth about the delusive nature of the ego-entity...

I would understand "the delusive nature of the ego-entity"  to mean that the "ego", the sense of selfhood, of personal identity, is considered  by "the psychologists" to be a form of delusion. (But that suggests a twist for the Cartesian principle: "I am deluded, therefore I am." )

The author goes on to refer to the sense of self, "the ego-feeling", as having only "relative value":

> ... the mere relative value of the ego-feeling ...

Again, this is the view allegedly held by "the psychologists" who are under the influence of
"the newest knowledge". The self has no *absolute* value of its own. Under the influence of the newest knowledge, the individual is regarded as having no intrinsic worth, no sacrosanctity, no inviolability; he is but a "tiny man", and dependent on the world.

The quoted passage doesn't explain the nature of that dependency  but ends with a rhetorical flourish that is meant to show the individual is a mere speck: "the inexhaustible and complex working factors of the world".

The author doesn't make this comparison, but I think it's apt: the ego is like Icarus in the painting by Brueghel, who is merely a leg and a tiny splash in the lower right corner of the painting as the commerce of the world occupies most of the picture. So maybe this "newest knowledge" isn't all that new.

[image: Fall of Icarus]